# Java Audio Clip is not stopping at right time

Tags: java, audio-playback

I wrote a program to start and stop a wav file in Java which will run on pi 3/b. 
The program works well in windows pc but it doesn't works good in pi (Raspbian Installed). It stops the audio clip after a second or two.

```
String filename = "cpu2x-jtfe7.wav";
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename)));
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                try {               
                        clip.start();
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }           
            }

        });
stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                

                clip.stop();                

            }

        });
```

Comment: i think that you are missing some info .... how do you start and stop the clip?

Comment: @jsotola I have paste the code here.. You can take a look